# PHP include partial file name

Tags: php, include, partial

So I've been looking for an option in PHP I'm not sure exists, but maybe I'm just overlooking the solution as I often do. I'd like to use includes in my PHP to break up my code into smaller bite-sized chunks. I'd like to make the include look for a part of the filename and not the whole name.

So for example. I have 1 file and 3 sub-files.

- jobs.php

  - jobs_view_simple.php
  - jobs_view_detail.php
  - jobs_view_print.php

In the jobs.php file I have 3 includes for the various needs enclosed in some logic.

```
include 'partials/jobs_view_simple.php';
include 'partials/jobs_view_detail.php';
include 'partials/jobs_view_print.php';
```

Is there a way in PHP that I can point to the subfile by referencing the last word/s. Similarly to how wordpress has [get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part). I think this would be helpful for me in this project, but I'm not sure how this is possible. Maybe this is a function I will need to write that doesn't already exist.

Thoughts?

Comment: This what you are looking for? http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to use `glob()` so you should simply be able to do this:

```
foreach (glob("partials/jobs*.php") as $filename) {
    include $filename;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1):

Extending on what Pitchinnate has said, you can create a function to do this

```
function includePartial($partial) {

    foreach (glob("partials/".$partial."_view_*.php") as $filename) {
        include $filename;
    }

}
```

Then you can just do

```
includePartial('jobs');
```